# Weird space in HTML & CSS design - can't get rid of it

Tags: html, css

I am creating a design in css & html. But a box which I want to have 100% width leaves ugly space to the right. I have no idea what causes this.

The div tag I want to have 100% width is called #view1.

http://jsfiddle.net/zBpAE/

```
#view1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
```

}

```
<div id="view1">
                    Choose the option suiting you best
            </div>
```

I'd really appreciate your help as I've been stuck with this issue for more than one hour now.

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: please also include the HTML and CSS in your question, as pastebin data might get deleted and this question will then be irrelevant to anyone else trying to find a similar answer in the future...

Comment: Can't post links so don't post links, rather.

Comment: I don't see it happening in JSFiddle, but from your first code samples posted I would assume it's from the 20px margin you gave one of the divs.

Comment: I concure with James, I see it in your jfid, its that 20px padding, lose it. James, you gotta scroll over then you see it. It took me a moment to see it.

Comment: Your list HTML is invalid. The only child of a UL element is an LI.

Comment: If you don't want to remove the padding, you could try out [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) (try `padding-box` or `border-box`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding: 20px;` from `<div id='first'></div>`:

```
#first {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        background: url('images/background1.png') #99307f no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, width does not include padding, so your width is effectively 100% + 40px.

Answer (score 1):

Your first div (#first) has width: 100% and padding: 25px ... that results in a width larger than the window's width ... remove the padding or set box-sizing: border-box;